# is fcvtzs d0,d0 really an AArch64 SIMD instruction?

Tags: assembly, simd, arm64, instruction-set, instructions

`gcc` seems to classify `fcvtzs d0,d0` as as SIMD instruction, but `clang` does not. Who is right?

```
$ cat toto.s
    fcvtzs d0,d0
$ aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-10 -mcpu=cortex-a53+nosimd -c toto.s
toto.s: Assembler messages:
toto.s:1: Error: selected processor does not support `fcvtzs d0,d0'
$ clang -target aarch64-linux-gnu -mcpu=cortex-a53+nosimd -c toto.s
```

Comment: Do you actually have a Cortex-A53 device that supports floating-point but not SIMD?  I'd expect that most chips would either support both, or support neither; in the latter case you would want `-mcpu=cortex-a53+nosimd+nofp` and then I assume both assemblers should reject `fcvtzs`.

Comment: I'm trying to benchmark floating-point code with and without SIMD, and `+nosimd` seems to be the way to go to prevent gcc from generating SIMD instructions.

Comment: Like in James's answer, I don't think there's any official categorization of instructions as "FP" versus "SIMD", so it may be just an arbitrary decision by the compiler authors.  But for benchmarking, I would guess that what you want to look at is not the specific instructions, but the auto-vectorization optimization more generally.  Which IIRC you can disable with `-fno-tree-vectorize`.

Answer (score 2):

You’re far in to the arcane classification of instructions as practically speaking FP and Advanced SIMD are always available together.

I would read the [Arm definition of FCVTZS](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-12/SIMD-FP-Instructions/FCVTZS--vector--integer---Floating-point-Convert-to-Signed-integer--rounding-toward-Zero--vector--) as supporting GCC’S classification of the SISD form of FCVTZS (reading and writing D registers) as an instruction that requires `+simd`. The reasoning would be the encoding class of the instruction (Scalar single-precision and double-precision) and the shared pseudo-code calling `CheckFPAdvSIMDEnabled64`.

I say the question gets a bit arcane, because the architecture pseudocode definition of `CheckFPAdvSIMDEnabled64` looks like this!

```
AArch64.CheckFPAdvSIMDEnabled()
    AArch64.CheckFPEnabled();
```

One technicality; your error message comes from the assembler not GCC; until [recently](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2021-March/567458.html) these two tools also disagreed with each other.